# CAD vector graphic editor

Tags: vector-graphics, cad

I want to make some vector graphic icons but what I sadly found out any of simple vector graphic editor do not support CAD-like functions like make line length depends of other line or constrain angle between them.

It was easier to find a simple CAD program like SolveSpace that can export to .svg file and then edit it in a vector graphic software. But clearly, it is not ideal solution.

So I am looking for a simple, free, linux program for vector graphics but with CAD functions. Do you know any?

Comment: The most likely answer to this question there is no such program.

Comment: Some of these CAD-like functions can be achieved in Inkscape utilizing simple tools like the transformations dialog or grouping.  For example, grouping makes line lengths interdependent in a group. So if you could elaborate in more detail which functions you are missing, then someone might be able to check if there is an alternative way using existing functions.

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely take a look at [OpenSCAD](https://www.openscad.org/) (also called "the programmers solid 3D CAD modeler) - it is more of a 3D compiler than an actual modeler. The main difference to other CAD softwares is, that it parses scripts.
As @GerardFalla mentioned, [FreeCAD](https://www.freecadweb.org/) is also amazing. I am using it since years.
There is a video on YouTube which I can recommend, titled [CAD Battle - OpenSCAD vs. FreeCAD](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OP0zI0k9gOs).

Answer (score 0):

### Antimony

This is probably not a perfect match and rather a shot in the dark.

Website: https://github.com/mkeeter/antimony

Screenshots and demo videos can be seen at http://www.mattkeeter.com/projects/antimony/3/

- Quoting the website: "Antimony is a computer-aided design (CAD) tool from a parallel universe."
  It is neither a classic CAD nor a classic real vector graphic software because you describe all geometric shapes in a data-flow diagram (similar to Blender nodes). The shapes' ports, such as x, y position, width and height, can be connected to ports from other shapes to create dependencies.
- Export possibilities: I am not sure about SVG and don't have a Fedora machine at hand. [Searching through the code](https://github.com/mkeeter/antimony/search?q=svg&type=Code&utf8=%E2%9C%93) doesn't bring up any promising part hinting at SVG export, though.
- Free
- Also runs on Linux
  A [community-supported package exists for Fedora](https://admin.fedoraproject.org/pkgdb/package/antimony/). For other distributions you have to build from source.

Comment: unfortunately Antimony is not solution of my problem. In this case is worse than SolveSpace (I did not found export to SVG too) BUT it is small, buggy, limited-feature CAD software with unlimited possibile due to simple edit (/create) scripts in python. I am sure that I will use Antimony in future for other stuff so big thanks you for this recommendation!

Answer (score 0):

Well, long ago I used [**FreeCAD**](https://www.freecadweb.org/) on linux, and it seemed to do what I needed pretty well - it's still around as a running project, is pretty full-featured, and it'll handle SVG output.

Maybe also look into [**OnShape**](https://www.onshape.com/) if you want collaborative tools and no reliance on single-platform, single-format - just as powerful as FreeCAD - if not more; it's browser based when used on desktop, though native App based on iOS and Android.

Answer (score -1):

If you need a CAD program you can try something like [QCAD](https://qcad.org/en/) or [BrisCAD](https://www.bricsys.com/en-intl/)

Comment: QCAD has no parametric features and BrisCAD has them only in the Pro version. And parametric editing was one feature OP asked for.